# How can i throw an exception in Q#?

Tags: exception, q#

I try to write an algorithm in Q#. In some cases the algorithm can not calculate a result with success because the user passed some bad arguments. In this case i want to throw an exception and now i wonder: Is it possible to throw and catch exceptions in Q#?

If yes: how can i do that and what is the proper way of exception-handling in Q#?

If no: why? are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the cases in which `catch` clauses are especially helpful in general-purpose languages look somewhat like handling I/O errors, in that they are very difficult to predict and deal with through ordinary flow control. By contrast, Q# programs are intended to be predictable in their execution so that functors like `Adjoint` and `Controlled` can generate appropriate transformations of programs as part of larger quantum algorithms.

That said, as you point out, there are times where one cannot sensibly proceed from some condition. Thus, Q# provides a `fail` statement that operates similarly to a `throw` statement (but takes a `String` rather than an exception object), but does not provide an analogue to a `try`–`catch` block. The `fail` statement is intended to communicate to the C# host program that a Q# program cannot sensibly proceed, and is useful for cases such as when a user passes bad instance. For instance, this is used throughout the [`Facts.qs`](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/master/Standard/src/Diagnostics/Facts.qs) file in the standard libraries to implement classical assertion functions such as [`EqualityWithinToleranceFact`](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/master/Standard/src/Diagnostics/Facts.qs#L33):

```
function EqualityWithinToleranceFact(actual : Double, expected : Double, tolerance : Double) : Unit {
    let delta = actual - expected;
    if (delta > tolerance or delta < -tolerance) {
        fail $"Fact was false. Expected: '{expected}'. Actual: '{actual}'";
    }
}
```